# Mysql Database Layout

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have created the following database layout, and started coding the application. The more I read, the more I realize my database layout is probably incorrect / inefficient / a bad idea. Before I develop too much code using this layout, I want to make sure I am doing it "correctly".

Basically I have a list of ~2000 stores, and a list of ~50 promotional codes. I need to store whether or not each code is valid at each store. Right now I chose to store each store number as a column header, with the first column containing all of the different possible codes. [Here's an image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/121443/pj-stackexchange-help1.png) of part of the table so far (1 represents the code being valid, 0 invalid at that store).

The promotional codes will change relatively frequently, but the store numbers should be relatively static, and not change very much.

This is my first time creating a database from scratch like this, and I am a beginner at using mysql, so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better use a table for your stores. If you don't, when one store will be added you'll spend a lot of time to add a new field...

Here is what I would do:

```
table store will contains your 2000s stores
    id
    name

table code will contains your 50 codes
    id
    name

table code_store will contains only the valid codes ID, and related store_id(no need to save invalid ones I guess)
    code_id
    store_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this sounds like the correct approach - Sam seems to have the same idea too. I'm glad I asked before I got too far!

Is it standard practice to store an id for each item, instead of storing just the name?

Comment: It's an usual approach, yes. It's because MySQL is faster on comparing integer than strings. It's also because, this way, you can change the name without affecting the rest of the database.

Answer (score 2):

This type of relation is called many-to-many. I typically have three table for this type of situation. One table for the stores, one for the promo codes, and a third relational table that would have two columns: the store id and the promo id.

Comment: The third relational table would have "stores"x"promo codes" ids? So for my example of 2000 stores, and 50 promo codes, I would have 100,000 rows, correct?

Comment: You would have 1 row for each store x assigned promo code. You would not have a row for an unassigned store x promo code combination. You can then query for the promo codes by store, or the stores by promo code. So you would have a maximum of 100,000 rows if every store had every promo code. Realistically, you would have 2,000 stores x average number of assigned promo codes per store for your approximate row count.